JavaScript listen to input value change programmatically
I'm trying to figure out where the value of an input is getting changed via JavaScript
My input looks like:
<input type="text"
       size="1"
       name="MyDatePicker"
       role="combobox"
       autocomplete="off"
       >

I typed the following in my browser's Console:
function handleChange(event) {debugger;}       

document.getElementsByName('MyDatePicker')[0].addEventListener('change', handleChange)
document.getElementsByName('MyDatePicker')[0].addEventListener('input', handleChange)

But I'm not hitting the handleChange function.
Is there a way to fire an event when the value of an input is changed programmatically, not through the UI?

There is no event fired when the value of an input is changed programmatically, so what you've tried will not work. You'll need to trawl through the code to find the source.

I wonder if it's possible to change a property of the input such that it throws an error when it's changed programmatically.

You could do that with a MutationObserver, but it would only point you back at your own code, not the mystery logic which is updating the value

You could add a global input handler and filter on the input name.
Now, you can dispatch an input event that bubbles-up.
You can use event.isTrusted to determine if the event was fired normally or programatically.


// Add a global listener
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  // Filter on the name
  if (event.target.name === 'MyDatePicker') {
    handleChange(event); // Forward the event
  }
});

// Handle as if we attached this to input[name="MyDatePicker"]
function handleChange(event) {
  const { target: { value }, isTrusted } = event;
  console.log('Current value:', value, '| Is trusted?', isTrusted);
}

// Fire the change event (bubble up to the global handler)
const element = document.querySelector('input[name="MyDatePicker"]');
setInputValue(element, 'F');

// Set the input element's value and fire the change event
function setInputValue(inputElement, value, bubbles=true) {
  inputElement.value = value;
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input', { bubbles }));
}
<input
  type="text"
  name="MyDatePicker"
  role="combobox"
  size="1"
  autocomplete="off">




Your time might be better spent finding the duplicates to such obvious questions...

You are still firing a new event. That could've be done without adding a global handler as you can dispatch the event directly to the input element, and a handler on the input element will catch it. Also, if the user can add a dispatchEvent when modifying it programmatically, he can just call handleChange directly instead.
